# What is the most efficient way to perform an INSERT based on whether it already exists?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am performing a great deal of inserts from a detail table into a summary table within SQL Server. I am currently using LEFT OUTER JOINs to determine if the row from the detail table already exists in the summary table prior to inserting it like the example below:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
       (columnA
       ,columnB
       ,columnC)
SELECT 
    b.columnA, 
    b.columnB, 
    b.columnC
FROM TableB b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA a
        on a.columnA = b.columnA
WHERE
    a.columnA IS NULL
```

I've found that this method takes a considerable amount of time even if there are no rows to insert because it has to compare all rows to determine what already exists. In this scenario I would normally consider adding a flag to `TableB` to say what rows have been inserted.

However there are several different scenarios for a row in `TableB` to be inserted into `TableA` which would require several flags and I would prefer not to use the storage space as `TableB` is VERY LARGE and getting LARGER.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you try to use the merge statements instead? I think sql-server does some additional optimization when using that instead.

Comment: Can you also show PKs and indexes on these tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (columnA, columnB, columnC)
SELECT 
    b.columnA, 
    b.columnB, 
    b.columnC
FROM TableB as b
where not exists (select 1 from TableA as xx where xx.columnA = b.columnA) ;
```

Comment: Wow, good suggestion.  I altered one of my smaller scripts that currently has no records to insert but previously still took almost 3 minutes to run and after applying your method it took 1 second.  Thanks!  Guess I didn't fully understand the "exists" keyword.